# What is a software fault in testing?

Tags: testing

I'm taking a grad class on software testing and we spent a whole class on the difference between faults, errors, and failures.  I was dissatisfied by the definition of a software fault in testing.  What's your definition?

Comment: How about providing definitions of all three as defined by your lecturer?

Comment: Yea, why not write down the definitions and explain why you're dissatisfied.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You might be interested in this [SE Radio](http://www.se-radio.net/podcast/2007-11/episode-77-fault-tolerance-bob-hanmer-pt-1) podcast where iirc, they're described as:

- fault:  The actual 'mistake' in the code
- error:  The bad state in the system that results from the fault.
- failure:  The variation from expected behaviour observed by the user as a result of the error.

Answer (score 5):

A **failure** occurs when the observed behaviour differs from the expected one. Note that the reference is the expected behaviour, not the specification, since even the spec could be false.

An **error** is the part of the system state which may lead to a failure.

A **fault** is the cause of an error. A software fault lies in software, a hardware fault lies in hardware.

You can find a deep overview of dependability concepts in [Dependabilty and its threats: a taxonomy](http://rodin.cs.ncl.ac.uk/Publications/avizienis.pdf), by Algirdas Avižienis, Jean-Claude Laprie & Brian Randell.

Answer (score 1):

According to the ISQTB a fault is a defect. There definition of a defect is as follows:

**defect:** A flaw in a component or system that can cause the component or system to fail to perform its required function, e.g. an incorrect statement or data definition. A defect, if encountered during execution, may cause a failure of the component or system.

**failure:** Deviation of the component or system from its expected delivery, service or result.

Basically, defects, bugs and errors are the same.

Answer (score 1):

In reality, it doesn't matter.  Academic papers tend to be all over the map with the terminology they use.  In industry there is more certainly not an accepted definition of each.  Moreover, no one in industry cares what the difference might be.  Fault, error, failure, bug, they are all treated about the same.

Comment: Actually, I am having a course on Chalmers now about Software Quality, and industry cares about them, at least Ericsson since a lot of lectures are performed by their employees.

Answer (score 0):

error---this may be human error i.e.misunderstanding of requirements & spec

fault---- error leads to fault

if developers misunderstands the requirements then he should code as per his understanding which leads to error in actual code.

failure---- fault leads to failure

if developer did wrong coding then s/w should give incorrect o/p which may leads to failure of application.

Comment: So error leads to fault, fault leads to failure, failure leads to.. suffering?

Answer (score 0):

Fault Types in testing are:

- Business Logic (B): Fault related to requirements
- Functional and Logical(F): fault related to functionality and logic
- Look and Feel (L):Faults related to GUI
- Performance (P): Faults related to performance
- Recoverability (R)
- Security (S)
- Replication (RL):fault related to data replication

  no comprende

Answer (score 0):

Error: A discrepancy between a computed, observed, or measured value or condition and the true, specified, or theoretically correct value or condition. This can be a misunderstanding of the internal state of the software, an oversight in terms of memory management, confusion about the proper way to calculate a value, etc.

Failure: The inability of a system or component to perform its required functions within specified performance requirements. See: bug, crash, exception, and fault.

Bug: A fault in a program which causes the program to perform in an unintended or unanticipated manner. See: anomaly, defect, error, exception, and fault. Bug is terminology of Tester.

Fault: An incorrect step, process, or data definition in a computer program which causes the program to perform in an unintended or unanticipated manner. See: bug, defect, error, exception.

Defect:Commonly refers to several troubles with the software products, with its external behavior or with its internal features.

Answer (score 0):

Error : The programmer makes a mistake (also called an error)

Defect : The programmer introduces a bug (also called a defect) into the code.

Bug  : The tester executes the part of the software that contains the bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Incident**:-When tester observes any discrepancy in the application then it will be a incident.

**Bug/Defect**:-When developer confirms with an Incidents then it will be a Bug.

**Fault**:-When Bug present in the application then it will be a Fault.

**Failure**:-When a Fault causes a system to fail then it is called as Failure.

Answer (score 0):

Software Testing Perspective means think yourself as Software Tester and you are testing a ready made software. First you will test it and find a a fault( defect). you will check software state which will be different than actual expected state this is an error. this error can leads you to a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Fault in software is a condition that causes a system to fail in performing its required function. A fault is the basic reason for software malfunction and is synonymous with the commonly used term bug.