# strip_tags() giving "can't use function return value in write context" when not writing

Tags: php, strip-tags

I got the error `Can't use function return value in write context` when trying to do assignment with `empty(strip_tags($string))` as the conditional in a ternary statement. So for testing, I got rid of the assignment and the ternary statement. But I'm still getting this error when it's apparently not in a write context.

Come to think of it, I'm not sure what `write context` means -- I thought it had to do with assignment, but I can't say that I know that for sure.

Why doesn't this work like I think it should? It seems pretty straight-forward to me.  What am I missing?

```
$ cat test.php
<?

$string = "<br/>";

if ( empty(strip_tags($string)) ) {
  echo "It's empty.\n";
} else {
  echo "It's not empty.\n";
}

$ php test.php
PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in test.php on line 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`empty()` is requiring you to act on a variable, rather than the output of a function.  Instead, store the output of `strip_tags()` into a variable.

```
$stripped = strip_tags($string);
if ( empty($stripped) ) {
  echo "It's empty.\n";
} else {
  echo "It's not empty.\n";
}
```

This is explained in the [`empty()` documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/function.empty.php):

> Note:
>   `empty()` only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`.

Comment: Ah! I thought it was `strip_tags()` misbehaving :)

Answer (score 4):

`empty` requires a variable. You pass a function return value, that's different.

You can work around that by putting it into brackets:

```
if ( empty((strip_tags($string))) ) {
```

But better do [like Michael wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586628/strip-tags-giving-cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context-when-not-w/7586682#7586682), this suggestion is some kind of a dirty hack. If interested, has been discussed in [Parentheses altering semantics of function call result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726589/parentheses-altering-semantics-of-function-call-result) and the [PHP Bug Report: #55222 Fatal Error disappears when using paranthesis](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55222).

Comment: +1. Didn't know parens would evaluate like that. Dirty hack, but interesting.