# Does array_shift and explode work?

Tags: php

I wonder if they disabled `array_shift` in  > PHP 5.2.6

```
$realid = array_shift(explode("-", $id));
```

Because this code was working fine on my server PHP Version 5.2.6, while is not working in another server with higher PHP version.

If so, is there anyway I can do the following:

For a URL like this `87262-any-thing-here.html` how can I get only the number, `87262`, so that I will use it to call any entry from database:

```
$qryrec="select * from mytable where id='$realid'";
$resultrec=mysql_query($qryrec) or die($qryrec);
$linerec=mysql_fetch_array($resultrec);
```

Is there any way to do the same without `array_shift`?

Comment: It works fine on 5.3. Anyway you can do the same using regexp

Comment: `array_shift` works fine in PHP 5.2.6 and beyond.  http://ideone.com/NnGIL

Comment: *sigh* "Not working" is **never** a good error description. What happens or doesn't happen? What errors do you get?

Comment: You should rather use `current(explode(..))` anyway, or better yet `strtok($id, "-")` if you only want the first part.

Comment: `php -r 'var_dump(array_shift(explode("-", "87262-any-thing-here.html")));'` Prints `string(5) "87262"`. Update your question and provide full inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Please specify which version the other server is running. Also, try running `$buf = explode ("-", $id); $realid = array_shift ($buf);`, it might be a bug in your specific PHP version.

Comment: strtok($id, "-") works perfect ~ thanks everybody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$realid = explode("-", $id);
$realid = $realid[0];
```

Comment: 1.) I use the $realid = $realid[0]; construct allways if I don't need the rest of the array, as it frees the memory used by the rest. 

2.) From my reading the construct to reading the first element of an int-based array is $array[0].

3.) AFAIK array_shift() needs a reference parameter. The output of a function is not one. This might have easily become stricter or less strict in different PHP versions.

4.) Not trusting in PHP "working as I intend, not as I write" seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** To obtain the decimal value at the beginning of a string, you can use `sscanf`:

```
$url = '87262-any-thing-here.html';
list($realid) = sscanf($url, '%d');
```

In case the URL has no decimal number at the beginning, `$realid` will be `NULL`. With `explode` you will get an undefined result depending on URL.

---

[`array_shift`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_shift) by it's function reference needs a variable:

---

[image]

---

(see as well: [*Passing by Reference*](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php))

But you give it a function:

```
 $realid = array_shift(explode("-", $id));
```

I would not expect it to always properly work because of that. Additionally this can trigger warnings and errors on some installations.

Instead use a variable:

```
 $ids = explode("-", $id);
 $realid = array_shift($ids);
 unset($ids);
```

Or in your case:

```
 list($realid) = explode("-", $id);
```

which will assing the first element of the array returned by `explode` to `$realid`. See [`list`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/list).

Comment: What are you talking about?  `array_shift(explode("-", $id));` works fine (I think it throws a E_STRICT warning in PHP 5.3 though).

Comment: php will simply evaluate the explode() before passing it as an argument. and explode returns an array so it is fine.

Comment: @Rocket: Works does not mean is. PHP versions differ and so do error logging configurations, e.g. `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference` - I would stick to the documentation of the function at first.

Comment: @hakre: Where in the documentation does it say I can't do `array_shift(explode("-", $id));`?

Comment: @hakre: It seems to throw a strict warning, but still works.  http://codepad.viper-7.com/GRS3At

Comment: @Rocket: I added a screenshot which highlights it. The error I pasted earlier is the same as in your codepad link (even from ;)).

Comment: @hakre: Ah, didn't notice the error in your earlier comment.  Anyway, I didn't realize passing `explode()` as a reference was bad.  Learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: @Rocket: Now as you know the problem, here is a PHP hack that prevents the warning ;) (but I discourage using it for production code because this might not work in the future): http://codepad.viper-7.com/BOtWEU

Comment: @hakre: Heh, wrapping it in `()`.  Neat.

Comment: @David Chan: But the returned array is not in variable context. See my previous comment how you can get into that context somehow, if you dislike to use a variable.

Comment: @Rocket: See this question: [Parentheses altering semantics of function call result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6726589/367456)