# Is it possible to inline access a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP I have the following construct

```
$a = array(-1 => '-', 0 => '?', 1 => '+')[1];
```

which gives a syntax error. Is it still possible to do such things in one convenient line avoiding multiple if/else clases or switch/select statements? I was thinking at python where this work fine:

```
a = {-1:'-', 0:'?', 1:'+'}[1]
```

Comment: Array dereferencing has been available since PHP 5.4

Comment: Why not just using `print '?'` ? Looks simpler.. :)

Comment: @JohnConde Nice (news to me) - listed as '[function array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)'

Comment: I need this to work in PHP4, and I just was giving an example (of course the '1' is a variable with different possible values 0, -1 and 1)....

Comment: PHP4?! Are you serious?!

Comment: Why are you using `PHP 4`

Comment: @Alex Just out of curiosity, why PHP 4? I don't want to judge your motivation, just want to hear from you.

Comment: I am working in a company on a large (and old!) software system written in PHP4. I am not sure if I can convince the business people to spend a lot of money to completly rewrite this system in a more convenient (and newer) language...

Comment: @Alex: (IMHO) There's not a massive amount of work [migration to PHP 5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php).  Perhaps you could try running on PHP 5 and running a regression test.  There may be no need to rewrite.

Comment: A PHP4 app having regression tests? That was a good laugh. Let me place my guess: Likely not ;)

Comment: @hakre I was thinking of a general [regression test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_test) - i.e. does the software still function if you run it on PHP 5; can you still do all you'd expect to do.  Does any behaviour change... It's always been quite common to do this stuff manually, especially in ye olden days.

Comment: @searlea: Yeah, but first you need to have the tests - manually or not. So for manual tests, you need to have the testsuite where it is written down what to test, how to test it and what qualifies are OK or FAIL. Many old applications are just tested once, then never again - unless something new comes in which will make that new test but nothing else. And then again: never again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works in `PHP` but only [5.5.0alpha1 - 5.5.0beta2](http://3v4l.org/T1V2l) you should use variables for now until a stable version is released.

```
$array =  array(-1 => '-', 0 => '?', 1 => '+');
print $array[1];
```

Another Intresting thing is that `PHP` Support [Function Array Dereferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) in `PHP 5.4` which means just wrapping your array in a function would make it work

```
function __($_) {
    return $_;
}

print __(array(-1 => '-', 0 => '?', 1 => '+'))[1];
```

Comment: Ok I see. I will use your suggestion, as I have to make this work anyway in PHP4...

Comment: Apart from the fact that this approach is terribly inefficient of course. `$x=$array[1];` takes about **40 nSec** on my laptop and `$x=__(array(-1 => '-', 0 => '?', 1 => '+'))[1]` takes **526 nSec** (based on a 10M iteration timer). OK the odd half mSec may not be significant, but if you are using this as a general approach, it could add up.  The issue here is that subroutine calls in PHP are a lot more costly than inline array access.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper function so you can do it in one line.

```
function array_get($array, $key)
{
    return $array[$key]
}

print array_get(array(-1 => '-', 0 => '?', 1 => '+'), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless which PHP version, if you're after that, you should have something in your function set:

```
function deref($subject) {
    return $subject;
}

function deref_array($array, $key) {
    return $array[$key];
}
```

This pair of very rudimentary functions allows you to tell the PHP parser most often what you need and mean:

```
$a = deref_array(array(-1 => '-', 0 => '?', 1 => '+'), 1);
```

In your concrete case you only need the second function, but the first one often is useful, too.

Answer (score -1):

The one-line way is:

```
$a = array_pop(array_slice(array(-1 => '-', 0 => '?', 1 => '+'), 1, 1));
```

Or in the general case:

```
$x = array_pop(array_slice(foo(), $offset, 1));
```

Which is of course horrible.

Comment: `array_pop` requires a variable - you don't use it here. Wrap it in parenthesis to fool PHP here, albeit that is probably not stable.

Comment: See as well: [Parentheses altering semantics of function call result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6726589/367456)

Comment: @hakre: I tested it on PHP 5.3 and it seems to work just fine, no variable reference required.

Comment: @sealea: That is because you don't have notices enabled in your development / test environment - which you *should* have - see http://eval.in/private/906625ae413256