# Notice and warnings-free way to retrieve the first element of array

Tags: php

Let's suppose we have 2 functions. First returns an array with `0..N` elements and the second need to return only the first element or `NULL` if there are no any.

Assuming we have such a code:

```
/**
 * return stdClass[]
 */
function foo()
{
    return ...;
}

/**
 * return stdClass|null
 */
function bar()
{
    $arr = foo();

    if ($arr) {
        return $arr[0];
    }
}
```

As you can see the implementation of `bar()` is boring.

If I used .NET then I would use `arr.FirstOrDefault()` method and it would suit the task perfectly.

What would be the most elegant way of doing that in php?

PS: the answers that generate any kind of warnings or notices are not accepted. As well as the ones that use `@` to suppress errors

Comment: `array_shift($arr)` doesn't generate notices (and returns null). -1 for boring question

Comment: @onetrickpony, just try `array_shift(foo());`

Comment: @onetrickpony It also has side effects, so for the purpose of peeking at a value it's considered bad form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `current()` for that, assuming `foo()` doesn't change the array pointer (using `next()` for instance), coupled with a ternary operator:

```
return current(foo()) ?: null;
```

This will obviously have odd results if you have scalars in your array that evaluate to `false`, but will work fine if all elements are objects.

Alternatively, to guard against modifications done by `foo()` you could use `reset()` as well:

```
return reset((foo())) ?: null;
```

**Warning**

Note the extra parentheses in the above code, they're not superfluous and is based on [a peculiarity in the language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6732876/1338292); this behaviour may change in the future, so you shouldn't rely on it. It would be safer to introduce a temporary variable.

Comment: You can find out more from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6732876/1338292).

Comment: just a note: that would return null if foo() returns false

Comment: @Wes "Let's suppose we have 2 functions. First returns an array with 0..N elements".

Comment: Yep, I *intentionally* declared `foo` to return `stdClass[]`

Comment: @Jack: you probably need to mention that the latter solution (with weird parentheses) is not an expected behaviour and may break one day

Comment: @zerkms Fair enough, added :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$return = ($arr = foo()) ? reset($arr) : null;
```

Why you cannont use current

```
function foo()
    {
    $array = array(1,2,3);
    next($array);
    return $array;
    }

echo current(foo()); // 2
```

Comment: "Why you cannont use current" --- because it wouldn't return `NULL`