# Strict standards error while exporting databse using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, export, syntax-error

This is my php code

```
//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
    echo 'Database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> successfully exported to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
    break;
case 1:
    echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
    break;
case 2:
    echo 'There was an error during export. Please check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
    break;
}
?>
```

when i try to execute this file. this error showing . **"Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\dbest.php on line 12"**

why this error showing? please helep me... thanks

Comment: Because of `$output=array()`. That's an expression, not a referencable variable. Don't try to inline-initialize it with the exec() call.

Answer (score 1):

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned

[Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

`$output=array()` is expression which returns value(empty array) but not variable. So it cannot be used as argument for fuctnions which gets this argument by reference.

But you could try to use [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726589/parentheses-altering-semantics-of-function-call-result).

Comment: thankz sectus. error disappeared.  but export not done. switch case 1 message showing now... :(